# Return elements of a list if equal to a condition

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have list in shape `a = [[aaa,1,0],[aba,1,2],[aca,0,3],...]`. By using a list comprehension I'd like to compose a new list if the second element of a row is equal to lets say 1. 
For now `b = [x[1]==1 for x in a]]` returns a boolean `true` `false` but I want those indexes return a new list.

Comment: So use a [Conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) instead?

Comment: you create wron list comprehension - you have to use `if` inside it.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
a = [[aaa,1,0],[aba,1,2],[aca,0,3],...]
output = [i for i in a if i[1] == 1]
```

or you can use `filter` which returns an iterator:

```
output = filter(lambda x: x[1] == 1, a)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
b = [i for i,j in enumerate(a) if j[1]==1]
```

It gives you the a list of indexes for which second item equals to `1`. If you want to get a list of items of which second item is equal to `1`,try this :

```
b = [i for i in a if i[1]==1]
```

If you want a slightly speedier version, use [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) method :

```
b = filter(lambda i: i[1]==1, a)
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess, this is the syntax you are looking for:

```
b = [x for x in a if x[1]==1]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
b = [ i for i,item in enumerate(a) if a[i][1]==1]
```

This will return a list containing indices of element in a , that satisfies the condition

if u want the items itself make it

```
b = [item for i,item in enumerate(a) if a[i][1]==1]
```